# LibreOffice using cells with macro in writer document

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have a LibreOffice calc table and a writer document. I want to use the fields from table inside document. This works for "regular" fields.

But one field (Barcode) has a formula from additional Makro/script. This formula works fine in calc. But if I open the "datasource" in writer I only see "#VALUE" instead. Also if I print a document, there is not the right data inserted.

Use of macro is turned on in writer and in calc.
What can I do to get the desired data into my writer document?

best regards
Johannes

Comment: There are many ways to insert values from Calc into Writer.  Which method did you use?

Comment: Hello @JimK
I use the mass-mail-assistent (I hope thats the correct translation). I like to keep it simple, so I do not want to use more vba-scripts.

Comment: What does "mass-mail-assistent" mean? Google guesses that it means http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Mail_Merge_Wizard. Please be specfiic about the steps required.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic*.  Expand to *My Macros -> Standard -> Module1*.  This location is under the user directory. 
 Managing locations is explained in detail at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/35598/where-are-lo-basic-macros-stored/.

Paste the following [user-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions).

```vb
Function EAN13_Barcode(index As Integer)
    myArray = Array(_
        "9783598215001","9783598215018","9783598215025",_
        "9783598215032","9783598215049","9783598215056",_
        "9783598215063","9783598215070","9783598215087")
    EAN13_Barcode = myArray(index)
End Function
```

Set up the spreadsheet like this (first image shows formulas, second shows values).

[image: spreadsheet example - formulas]
[image: spreadsheet example - values]

Note: If the macro is embedded in the Calc document rather than stored in the user directory, then `EAN13_Barcode()` will work only in Calc, not in Base or Writer.

Next, create a database link by going to *File -> New Database.*

- Connect to an existing database: Spreadsheet.
- Browse to the .ods file.
- Yes, register the database for me.
- Save as New Database.mdb.

The table in Base looks like this.

[image: table in Base]

Now in Writer, *View -> Data Sources*:

- Expand to New Database -> Tables -> Sheet 1.

[image: data sources window]

- Click in front of the row for the second record and drag to the main document area.
- Insert data as: Fields.
- Database columns are Barcode and FullName.
- Press OK.

[image: result]

The fields can be refreshed if the values change.  To do this, save the Calc spreadsheet and Writer document, close everything and then open the Writer document again.

Comment: Thank you for your very good explanation, but this also does not work. The macro inside a cell isn't executed when inserted/linked to a document.

https://imgur.com/a/SLHGl

You see: in row "Barcode" is just error "'#WERT"

Comment: I edited the answer to show a Data Sources image.  In your image, the left side of the Data Sources area does not look good.  It says "anschluesse" (connections) but does not seem to list any.  Can you take another screen capture that shows the entire left side?  Perhaps there is some problem with your installation.  What operating system, version and locale?

Comment: The left side is just cropped - looks good for real ;-) .
I tested this with two machines, both on Debian Testing with LibreOffice 5.2 .
The macro inside the cell isn't executed if database/spreadsheet is read by a linked document.
Now I use a different and not so comfortable way: I set up a second page in spreadsheet (instead of using writer) and placed my document there. Then I copy the desired row to the document-page and print it.

Comment: See here: https://imgur.com/a/aTWtX - the column "Barcode" is also "broken".
Or here with spreadsheet in background. https://imgur.com/a/Diqha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160992/discussion-between-jim-k-and-johannes-c-schulz).

Comment: @Johannes C. Schulz: Rewrote instructions to make it clear how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank for this! Great work! But, is this portable? I be afraid, that other users have trouble with using these solution because of importing the macro in MyMacros.

Comment: Well, this setup requires three files, so it does not sound like it's going to be easy to port regardless.  Perhaps there is a different way instead of a user-defined function.  If you want to explore this possibility, ask a new question explaining what the UDF does and what the writer document does, and see if there are alternatives that are more portable.  Add a link to this question.